# How to return a regex match conditionally in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can we elegantly return a possible string regex match without running the match twice?

```js
// Works fine, returns "pdf"
let ext = "file.with.extension.pdf".match(/\.([a-z]+)$/)[1];
```

```js
// Exception, we'd like just null or ''
let ext = "nofileextension".match(/\.([a-z]+)$/)[1];
```

```js
// Duplicate execution
let ext = "nofileextension".match(/\.([a-z]+)$/) && "nofileextension".match(/\.([a-z]+)$/)[1];
```

Is there no optional chaining `()?[1]` for a method which might return an array?

```js
let ext = "nofileextension".match(/\.([a-z]+)$/)?[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?.` and then the array indexing will only be done if an object is present to do it on:

```js
console.log("document123.pdf".match(/\.([a-z]+)$/)?.[1]);
console.log("nofileextension".match(/\.([a-z]+)$/)?.[1]);
```